# NSLog nsarray in nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multidimensional-array, nsarray

I created

```
NSArray *test = @[@[@1,@2,@3,@4], @[@3,@5,@6,@7]];
```

which will be considered as `nsarray` of `nsarray`.

but when I wanted to print it out with

```
NSLog (@"%@", test); or NSLog(@"%@", test[0]);
NSLog (@"%@", [test ObjectAtIndex: 0]);
```

the process always ends with

```
NSException; Signal SIGABRT 
Reason: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', '-[__NSArrayI compare:]:unrecognized selector  sent to instance 0x608000262788'
```

Please help me, could someone tell me how to deal with this problem? And in general how to debug theproblem `'Signal SIGABRT'`?

Comment: u can use `[[[test objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex:0] ` since  your array contains more array inside it

Comment: You might want to edit your message using the code formatting.

Comment: You are making a fundamental mistake.  '@' is a symbol used before a string.  1, 2, 3, 4 and other integers are not strings.

Comment: @ElTomato, what do you mean? @1 will be a NSNumber. Using `NSLog(@"%@")` in this case is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ElTomato You are absolutely wrong. If you wanted add int in array then put @ in front of Int or use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]`

Comment: @Tj3n shouldn't it be enough to do`[[test objectAtIndex: 0] objectAtIndex: 0]` ?

Comment: Are you comparing those array objects? As you shared, -[__NSArrayI compare:]: unrecognized selector  sent..

Comment: Your given code is working fine. There is some other issue in code. use break point and debug your code step by step.

Answer (score 2):

`SIGABRT` means in general that there is an uncaught exception. There should be more information on the console.

I execute this code is my xcode, and it ran properly.

Take a look on this demo, Hope you get better knowledge

I use this code

```
 NSArray *array = @[@"1111132324"];
 NSLog(@"array : %@", array);
 NSLog(@"array[0] : %@", array[0]);
```

and i get output:

[image]

as you see when I print array it gives output in braces '(' and ')'. If i print just single element of array which is string here, there is no braces.

As you said you have array in array, try like this

```
NSArray *arrayOuter = @[@"1111132324"];
NSArray *arrayInner = @[arrayOuter];

NSLog(@"array : %@", arrayInner);
NSLog(@"array[0] : %@", arrayInner[0]);
NSLog(@"array[0] : %@", arrayInner[0][0]);
```

see output:

[image]

You can extend your hierarchy of dictionary or array or mix of array-dictionary (doesn't matter) upto n times like this.

every key(for dict)/index(for array) is must be in that hierarchy level. Style of getting data is from upper hierarchy to lower hierarchy.

For dictionary

```
dict[@"key1"][@"key2"]...[@"keyN"]
```

for mix dict-arr

```
//upper object must be dictionary so start with key.
dict[@"key1"][0][@"key"]..[@"keyN"] or object index.
```

for mix array - dict

```
//upper object must be array so start with index.
dict[0][@"key1"][@"key"]..[@"keyN"] or object index.
```

**NOTE:** Sequence of key and index is according to the object at that hierarchy.

Comment: There are int variables in question used in array and you are using string variables in array, means you are testing wrong code. please read question again

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be work for you.

```
NSArray *test = @[@[@1,@2,@3,@4],
                @[@3,@5,@6,@7]];

NSLog(@"Test array: %@", test);
NSLog(@"Test firstObject: %@", [test firstObject]);
NSLog(@"Test lastObject : %@", [test lastObject]);
NSLog(@"Test objectAtIndex :%@", [test objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Test objectAtIndex 2 :%@", test[0]);
```